# Step one in Android?

Tags: android

I operate a field service company. I am searching for an app to install on an android tablet with no other function than be a tool for my company. The app needs to have forms,map APIs,a data base,calendar,VOIP,Text all working together.

I have tried countless trials searching for a pre-built solutions and have not found anything that fits my need. I have learned a great deal about what can be done the problem is I don't know how to put it together.

I have maintained my own website for the last decade for my company and have managed my SEO pretty well but beyond being able to recognize some HTML or CSS I do not have any knowledge of code.

I have Android Studio installed and it finally seems to be functioning properly.I now am trying to learn the basics on Youtube and other tutorials

I was hoping someone here could help me get on the right path opposed to randomly choosing this video or that web page. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.I am looking forward to entering this new world and hopeful to get started on the best foot forward. Thanks

Comment: This is far too broad, and tutorial request are offtopic here. Try Reddit.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by some of your requirements (e.g., VOIP) and what the breadth and depth of this app is, it might take a team of developers some months to create. For one person starting with zero programming experience, it might take years, particularly if this is a part-time project. So, I recommend that you put the tools aside for a bit and get some quotes from consultants for what it would take to build your desired app. Even if you do not wind up using those specific consultants, it will give you a better sense for the level of effort that is involved in achieving your vision.